# QGIS how to select a set of features in field calculator expression

Tags: qgis, expression, geometry-generator

I try to connect one feature from a polygon layer to many in a point layer, using geometry generator and expression calculator in the polygon layer.
If I can connect 1 polygon to all the points,

```
shortest_line(geometry(get_feature('mylayer', 'myattribute', 'myvalue')), 
geometry($currentfeature))
```

I can't connect one polygon to a set of points i.e. I can't select some points with a specific value in a field.

```
shortest_line(geometry(get_feature('mylayer', 'myattribute', 'myvalue')), 
geometry(*only_the_polygons_with_a_specific_attribute_value*))
```

I tried `get_feature`and `attribute` but I failed.
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: If it's the layer you're working on look into `collect()` and filter by your specific attribute value; if it's another layer you can do something similar within the `aggregate()` function

Comment: See this answer here, seems to be a similar approach and could help you achieving what you want, adapting the expression to your needs: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381819/88814